# Error on running nsolid on Mac OSX

Tags: nsolid

I get the following error when running nsolid on MAC OSX. I am running a simple node REPL application on the node runtime env as specified in the Quick Start Guide.
Error:

> {"time":"2016-08-23T13:48:59.943Z","hostname":"xxxxxxx-mbpr","pid":3867,"level":"error","name":"nsolid-proxy","err":{"name":"Error","message":"client request timeout","stack":"Error: client request timeout\n    at onTimeout (/usr/local/nsolid/proxy/node_modules/nsolid-rpcclient/node_modules/client-request/request.js:113:17)\n    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)"}}

Comment: Is there anything else on `/tmp/nsolid-console.log`, `/tmp/nsolid-etcd.log` or `/tmp/nsolid-proxy.log`? are you using `nsolid-console` to launch all the services and then running the REPL using `nsolid-env`? Is this on the same local machine or inside a container?

Comment: All on the same OS X machine.

/tmp/nsolid-console.log
Server running on http://0.0.0.0:3000

no errors in the etcd log. I already shared the error in proxy.log.
Yes, I start everything using nsolid-console and then run node in nsolid-env

Answer (score 1):

`Error: client request timeout` means that the proxy can't reach the N|Solid process.

First you'll need to know the IP and PORT of the process registered, you can get it by running:

```
$ nsolid-cli ls

{"pid":2662,"hostname":"ns-work.local","app":"nsolid-default","address":"192.168.0.1:50549","id":"fd1190b2ce8f39e032cb262440dfba5408cde9fc"}
```

You can try to reach that IP and PORT using `curl` with:

```
$ curl http://192.168.0.1:50549/ping
PONG%
```

And it should return `PONG` if everything is OK or you can use `$ nsolid-cli ping` to `ping` your applications.

If for some reason you don't have network access to that IP registered to the N|Solid Hub, you can define it yourself when running your N|Solid process, a recommended way (when using the developer bundle) is to run it like:

```
$ NSOLID_SOCKET=localhost node server.js
```

So it will register with the local interface and the proxy will not have problems to reach it.